# What carrier names are used on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, carrier

I have read the questions and answers about how to get the carrier name on an iPhone using the CTCarrier class.  But I need to know what names are used for the more common carriers.  I know the name for AT&T, which is "AT&T" but I don't have test devices on Verizon, T-Mobile, etc.  Is there a list somewhere?

Comment: do you wanna get carrier name in ios

Comment: Our T-Mobile provider in Germany changed their name at least once since I'm an iPhone customer (since november 9th 2007). So I'm pretty sure that this is a value that can (and will) be change remotely by the carrier. I wouldn't rely on this value for anything. Currently, it says "`Telekom.de`".